# How to Make a call with Python Client Rancher

Tags: python, docker, curl, kubernetes, rancher

I hope you are doing well today. I have a question regarding this Rancher Python Client that I am currently working on. I'm trying to access this one of the single node containers and modify aspects of said container, but I don't really know where to begin. I was able to apply the API keys and print out the client using print(client).

Question: Could someone go through a mock call to this rancher api, specifically is there a way to change admin access regarding who gets access to what container from the api?

Thank You So Much.

GitHub Link: https://github.com/rancher/client-python

```
import rancher

client = rancher.Client(url='https://localhost:8443/v3',
                        access_key='<some valid access key>',
                        secret_key='<some valid secret key>')

# curl -s https://localhost:8443/v3/users?me=true
client.list_user(me='true')

# curl -s -X POST https://localhost:8443/v3/users -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "username" : "user1", "password": "Password1" }'
client.create_user(username='user1', password='Password1')

# curl -s -X PUT https://localhost:8443/v3/users/user-xyz123 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "description" : "A user" }'
user = client.by_id_user('user-xyz123')
client.update(user, description='A user')

# curl -s -X DELETE https://localhost:8443/v3/users/user-xyz123
user = client.by_id_user('user-xyz123')
client.delete(user)

# Links
# curl -s https://localhost:8443/v3/clusterRoleTemplateBindings?userId=user-xyz123
user = client.by_id_user('user-xyz123')
user.clusterRoleTemplateBindings()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, I have been using rancher 1.6 and not Rancher 2.x. The API does not work for rancher 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

To make a call with the client (get/post/put/delete), use the methods like this:

```
text_response = client._get(url=[ranchercluster/v3/clusters], access_key, secret_key)
```

For the others, just client._post(), client._put() and client._delete()